No Errors in SAP B1 SDK UI API Code, but Data Not Posting to Database
Despite having no errors in the code for adding a UDO in the SAP B1 SDK UI API, the data is not being posted to the database. How can this issue be resolved?
I have created the form here:
 private void CreateASNForm()
 {
     SAPbouiCOM.FormCreationParams oFormCreationParams = null;
     SAPbouiCOM.Item oItem = null;
     SAPbouiCOM.EditText oEditText = null;
     SAPbouiCOM.Button oButton = null;

     try
     {
         // Check if the form already exists
         SAPbouiCOM.Form oExistingForm = null;
         try
         {
             oExistingForm = SBO_Application.Forms.Item("ASNFrm");
         }
         catch (Exception)
         {
             // Form does not exist
         }

         if (oExistingForm != null)
         {
             // If the form exists but is not visible, close it
             if (!oExistingForm.Visible)
             {
                 oExistingForm.Close();
             }
             else
             {
                 // Form is visible, bring it to the front
                 oExistingForm.Select();
                 SBO_Application.SetStatusBarMessage("Advance Shipping Notification form is already open.", SAPbouiCOM.BoMessageTime.bmt_Short, false);
                 return;
             }
         }

         // Create form with UDO binding
         oFormCreationParams = (SAPbouiCOM.FormCreationParams)SBO_Application.CreateObject(SAPbouiCOM.BoCreatableObjectType.cot_FormCreationParams);
         oFormCreationParams.UniqueID = "ASNFrm";
         oFormCreationParams.FormType = "ASNFrm";
         oFormCreationParams.BorderStyle = SAPbouiCOM.BoFormBorderStyle.fbs_Sizable;
         oFormCreationParams.ObjectType = "WMS_ASN"; // Bind to UDO
         oForm = SBO_Application.Forms.AddEx(oFormCreationParams);
         oForm.Title = "Advance Shipping Notification";

         // Add DataSources
         SAPbouiCOM.DBDataSource oDBDataSourceHeader = oForm.DataSources.DBDataSources.Add("@WMS_ASN");
         SAPbouiCOM.DBDataSource oDBDataSourceLines = oForm.DataSources.DBDataSources.Add("@WMS_ASN_L");

         // Add header fields
         int top = 10;
         int left = 5;
         int width = 150;
         int height = 15;

         #region Header Document
         oItem = oForm.Items.Add("lblDocE", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_STATIC);
         oItem.Top = top;
         oItem.Left = left;
         oItem.Width = width;
         oItem.Height = height;
         SAPbouiCOM.StaticText oStaticText = (SAPbouiCOM.StaticText)oItem.Specific;
         oStaticText.Caption = "DocEntry";

         oItem = oForm.Items.Add("txtDocE", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_EDIT);
         oItem.Top = top;
         oItem.Left = left + width + 5;
         oItem.Width = width;
         oItem.Height = height;
         oEditText = (SAPbouiCOM.EditText)oItem.Specific;
         oEditText.DataBind.SetBound(true, "@WMS_ASN", "DocEntry");
         oEditText.Item.Enabled = false; // Read-only

         top += height + 5;

         oItem = oForm.Items.Add("lblContNr", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_STATIC);
         oItem.Top = top;
         oItem.Left = left;
         oItem.Width = width;
         oItem.Height = height;
         oStaticText = (SAPbouiCOM.StaticText)oItem.Specific;
         oStaticText.Caption = "Container Number";

         oItem = oForm.Items.Add("txtContNr", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_EDIT);
         oItem.Top = top;
         oItem.Left = left + width + 5;
         oItem.Width = width;
         oItem.Height = height;
         oEditText = (SAPbouiCOM.EditText)oItem.Specific;
         oEditText.DataBind.SetBound(true, "@WMS_ASN", "U_ContainerNumber");

         top += height + 5;

         oItem = oForm.Items.Add("lblBLNr", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_STATIC);
         oItem.Top = top;
         oItem.Left = left;
         oItem.Width = width;
         oItem.Height = height;
         oStaticText = (SAPbouiCOM.StaticText)oItem.Specific;
         oStaticText.Caption = "Bill of Lading Number";

         oItem = oForm.Items.Add("txtBLNr", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_EDIT);
         oItem.Top = top;
         oItem.Left = left + width + 5;
         oItem.Width = width;
         oItem.Height = height;
         oEditText = (SAPbouiCOM.EditText)oItem.Specific;
         oEditText.DataBind.SetBound(true, "@WMS_ASN", "U_BLNumber");

         top += height + 5;

         oItem = oForm.Items.Add("lblETA", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_STATIC);
         oItem.Top = top;
         oItem.Left = left;
         oItem.Width = width;
         oItem.Height = height;
         oStaticText = (SAPbouiCOM.StaticText)oItem.Specific;
         oStaticText.Caption = "ETA";

         oItem = oForm.Items.Add("txtETA", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_EDIT);
         oItem.Top = top;
         oItem.Left = left + width + 5;
         oItem.Width = width;
         oItem.Height = height;
         oEditText = (SAPbouiCOM.EditText)oItem.Specific;
         oEditText.DataBind.SetBound(true, "@WMS_ASN", "U_ETA");

         top += height + 5;

         oItem = oForm.Items.Add("lblETD", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_STATIC);
         oItem.Top = top;
         oItem.Left = left;
         oItem.Width = width;
         oItem.Height = height;
         oStaticText = (SAPbouiCOM.StaticText)oItem.Specific;
         oStaticText.Caption = "ETD";

         oItem = oForm.Items.Add("txtETD", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_EDIT);
         oItem.Top = top;
         oItem.Left = left + width + 5;
         oItem.Width = width;
         oItem.Height = height;
         oEditText = (SAPbouiCOM.EditText)oItem.Specific;
         oEditText.DataBind.SetBound(true, "@WMS_ASN", "U_ETD");

         top += height + 5;

         oItem = oForm.Items.Add("lblOrig", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_STATIC);
         oItem.Top = top;
         oItem.Left = left;
         oItem.Width = width;
         oItem.Height = height;
         oStaticText = (SAPbouiCOM.StaticText)oItem.Specific;
         oStaticText.Caption = "Origin";

         oItem = oForm.Items.Add("txtOrig", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_EDIT);
         oItem.Top = top;
         oItem.Left = left + width + 5;
         oItem.Width = width;
         oItem.Height = height;
         oEditText = (SAPbouiCOM.EditText)oItem.Specific;
         oEditText.DataBind.SetBound(true, "@WMS_ASN", "U_Origin");

         top += height + 5;

         oItem = oForm.Items.Add("lblDest", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_STATIC);
         oItem.Top = top;
         oItem.Left = left;
         oItem.Width = width;
         oItem.Height = height;
         oStaticText = (SAPbouiCOM.StaticText)oItem.Specific;
         oStaticText.Caption = "Destination";

         oItem = oForm.Items.Add("txtDest", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_EDIT);
         oItem.Top = top;
         oItem.Left = left + width + 5;
         oItem.Width = width;
         oItem.Height = height;
         oEditText = (SAPbouiCOM.EditText)oItem.Specific;
         oEditText.DataBind.SetBound(true, "@WMS_ASN", "U_Destination");

         top += height + 5;

         oItem = oForm.Items.Add("lblStat", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_STATIC);
         oItem.Top = top;
         oItem.Left = left;
         oItem.Width = width;
         oItem.Height = height;
         oStaticText = (SAPbouiCOM.StaticText)oItem.Specific;
         oStaticText.Caption = "Status";

         oItem = oForm.Items.Add("txtStat", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_EDIT);
         oItem.Top = top;
         oItem.Left = left + width + 5;
         oItem.Width = width;
         oItem.Height = height;
         oEditText = (SAPbouiCOM.EditText)oItem.Specific;
         oEditText.DataBind.SetBound(true, "@WMS_ASN", "U_Status");

         top += height + 15;
         #endregion

         #region Line Items: Grid / Matrix
         // Add a Matrix to the form for displaying line items
         oItem = oForm.Items.Add("matLines", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_MATRIX);
         oItem.Top = top;
         oItem.Left = 5;
         oItem.Height = 90;
         oItem.Width = 500;

         SAPbouiCOM.Matrix oMatrix = (SAPbouiCOM.Matrix)oItem.Specific;
         SAPbouiCOM.Columns oColumns = oMatrix.Columns;

         SAPbouiCOM.Column oColumn = oColumns.Add("colNo", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_EDIT);
         oColumn.TitleObject.Caption = "#";
         oColumn.Width = 30;
         oColumn.Editable = false; // Prevent focus on # column

         oColumn = oColumns.Add("colPO", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_EDIT);
         oColumn.TitleObject.Caption = "PO Number";
         oColumn.DataBind.SetBound(true, "@WMS_ASN_L", "U_PONum");
         oColumn.Width = 100;

         // Add ChooseFromList to the PO Number column
         SAPbouiCOM.ChooseFromListCollection oCFLs = oForm.ChooseFromLists;
         SAPbouiCOM.ChooseFromList oCFL;
         SAPbouiCOM.ChooseFromListCreationParams oCFLParams = (SAPbouiCOM.ChooseFromListCreationParams)SBO_Application.CreateObject(SAPbouiCOM.BoCreatableObjectType.cot_ChooseFromListCreationParams);
         oCFLParams.MultiSelection = false;
         oCFLParams.ObjectType = "22"; // 22 corresponds to the Purchase Order object type
         oCFLParams.UniqueID = "CFL_PO";
         oCFL = oCFLs.Add(oCFLParams);

         oColumn.ChooseFromListUID = "CFL_PO";
         oColumn.ChooseFromListAlias = "DocNum"; // Use the correct alias for the PO number in the target table

         oColumn = oColumns.Add("colIC", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_EDIT);
         oColumn.TitleObject.Caption = "Item Code";
         oColumn.DataBind.SetBound(true, "@WMS_ASN_L", "U_ItmCd");
         oColumn.Width = 100;

         // Add ChooseFromList to the form for item codes
         SAPbouiCOM.ChooseFromList oCFLItem;
         SAPbouiCOM.ChooseFromListCreationParams oCFLItemParams = (SAPbouiCOM.ChooseFromListCreationParams)SBO_Application.CreateObject(SAPbouiCOM.BoCreatableObjectType.cot_ChooseFromListCreationParams);
         oCFLItemParams.MultiSelection = false;
         oCFLItemParams.ObjectType = "4"; // 4 corresponds to the Item Master Data object type
         oCFLItemParams.UniqueID = "CFL_Item";
         oCFLItem = oForm.ChooseFromLists.Add(oCFLItemParams);

         // Assign the ChooseFromList to the item code column in the matrix
         SAPbouiCOM.Column oItemCodeColumn = oMatrix.Columns.Item("colIC");
         oItemCodeColumn.ChooseFromListUID = "CFL_Item";
         oItemCodeColumn.ChooseFromListAlias = "ItemCode";

         oColumn = oColumns.Add("colDesc", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_EDIT);
         oColumn.TitleObject.Caption = "Description";
         oColumn.DataBind.SetBound(true, "@WMS_ASN_L", "U_Desc");
         oColumn.Width = 150;

         oColumn = oColumns.Add("colQty", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_EDIT);
         oColumn.TitleObject.Caption = "Quantity";
         oColumn.DataBind.SetBound(true, "@WMS_ASN_L", "U_Qty");
         oColumn.Width = 80;

         oColumn = oColumns.Add("colUM", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_EDIT);
         oColumn.TitleObject.Caption = "Unit Measure";
         oColumn.DataBind.SetBound(true, "@WMS_ASN_L", "U_UM");
         oColumn.Width = 80;

         oColumn = oColumns.Add("colBat", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_EDIT);
         oColumn.TitleObject.Caption = "Batch Number";
         oColumn.DataBind.SetBound(true, "@WMS_ASN_L", "U_Batch");
         oColumn.Width = 100;

         oColumn = oColumns.Add("colMfg", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_EDIT);
         oColumn.TitleObject.Caption = "Manufacturing Date";
         oColumn.DataBind.SetBound(true, "@WMS_ASN_L", "U_MfgDt");
         oColumn.Width = 100;

         oColumn = oColumns.Add("colExp", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_EDIT);
         oColumn.TitleObject.Caption = "Expiration Date";
         oColumn.DataBind.SetBound(true, "@WMS_ASN_L", "U_ExpDt");
         oColumn.Width = 100;
         #endregion

         // Adjust the top position to add buttons below the matrix
         top = 280;

         // Add buttons for actions
         oItem = oForm.Items.Add("btnAdd", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_BUTTON);
         oItem.Visible = true;
         oItem.Top = top;
         oItem.Left = 5;
         oButton = (SAPbouiCOM.Button)oItem.Specific;
         oButton.Caption = "Add";

         oItem = oForm.Items.Add("btnCanc", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_BUTTON);
         oItem.Top = top;
         oItem.Left = 75;
         oButton = (SAPbouiCOM.Button)oItem.Specific;
         oButton.Caption = "Cancel";

         // Initialize matrix with one row
         AddRowToMatrix("ASNFrm");

         oForm.Visible = true;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         SBO_Application.SetStatusBarMessage("Error creating ASN form: " + ex.Message, SAPbouiCOM.BoMessageTime.bmt_Short, true);
     }
 }

We call it on the SBO_Application_ItemEvent(string FormUID, ref ItemEvent pVal, out bool BubbleEvent);
private void SBO_Application_ItemEvent(string FormUID, ref ItemEvent pVal, out bool BubbleEvent)
{
  if (pVal.EventType == BoEventTypes.et_ITEM_PRESSED && pVal.ItemUID == "btnAdd" && !pVal.BeforeAction)
  {
    HandleAddOrUpdate(pVal.FormUID);
  }
}

Code for Handling the Add or Update
 private void HandleAddOrUpdate(string FormUID)
 {
     try
     {
         oForm = SBO_Application.Forms.Item(FormUID);
         MessageBox.Show(FormUID);
         if (oForm.Mode != BoFormMode.fm_ADD_MODE && oForm.Mode != BoFormMode.fm_UPDATE_MODE)
         {
             SBO_Application.SetStatusBarMessage("Form is not in add or update mode.", BoMessageTime.bmt_Short, true);
             return;
         }

         // Start transaction
         oCompany.StartTransaction();

         // Ensure you have all data sources bound correctly
         SAPbouiCOM.DBDataSource oDBDataSourceHeader = oForm.DataSources.DBDataSources.Item("@WMS_ASN");
         SAPbouiCOM.DBDataSource oDBDataSourceLines = oForm.DataSources.DBDataSources.Item("@WMS_ASN_L");

         // Save header fields with error handling
         try
         {
             oDBDataSourceHeader.SetValue("U_ContainerNumber", 0, ((SAPbouiCOM.EditText)oForm.Items.Item("txtContNr").Specific).Value);
             oDBDataSourceHeader.SetValue("U_BLNumber", 0, ((SAPbouiCOM.EditText)oForm.Items.Item("txtBLNr").Specific).Value);
             oDBDataSourceHeader.SetValue("U_ETA", 0, ((SAPbouiCOM.EditText)oForm.Items.Item("txtETA").Specific).Value);
             oDBDataSourceHeader.SetValue("U_ETD", 0, ((SAPbouiCOM.EditText)oForm.Items.Item("txtETD").Specific).Value);
             oDBDataSourceHeader.SetValue("U_Origin", 0, ((SAPbouiCOM.EditText)oForm.Items.Item("txtOrig").Specific).Value);
             oDBDataSourceHeader.SetValue("U_Destination", 0, ((SAPbouiCOM.EditText)oForm.Items.Item("txtDest").Specific).Value);
             oDBDataSourceHeader.SetValue("U_Status", 0, ((SAPbouiCOM.EditText)oForm.Items.Item("txtStat").Specific).Value);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             SBO_Application.SetStatusBarMessage("Error setting header field values: " + ex.Message, BoMessageTime.bmt_Short, true);
             if (oCompany.InTransaction)
                 oCompany.EndTransaction(SAPbobsCOM.BoWfTransOpt.wf_RollBack);
             return;
         }

         // Save line items with error handling
         SAPbouiCOM.Matrix oMatrix = (SAPbouiCOM.Matrix)oForm.Items.Item("matLines").Specific;
         for (int i = 1; i <= oMatrix.RowCount; i++)
         {
             try
             {
                 oDBDataSourceLines.SetValue("U_PONum", i - 1, ((SAPbouiCOM.EditText)oMatrix.Columns.Item("colPO").Cells.Item(i).Specific).Value);
                 oDBDataSourceLines.SetValue("U_ItmCd", i - 1, ((SAPbouiCOM.EditText)oMatrix.Columns.Item("colIC").Cells.Item(i).Specific).Value);
                 oDBDataSourceLines.SetValue("U_Desc", i - 1, ((SAPbouiCOM.EditText)oMatrix.Columns.Item("colDesc").Cells.Item(i).Specific).Value);
                 oDBDataSourceLines.SetValue("U_Qty", i - 1, ((SAPbouiCOM.EditText)oMatrix.Columns.Item("colQty").Cells.Item(i).Specific).Value);
                 oDBDataSourceLines.SetValue("U_UM", i - 1, ((SAPbouiCOM.EditText)oMatrix.Columns.Item("colUM").Cells.Item(i).Specific).Value);
                 oDBDataSourceLines.SetValue("U_Batch", i - 1, ((SAPbouiCOM.EditText)oMatrix.Columns.Item("colBat").Cells.Item(i).Specific).Value);
                 oDBDataSourceLines.SetValue("U_MfgDt", i - 1, ((SAPbouiCOM.EditText)oMatrix.Columns.Item("colMfg").Cells.Item(i).Specific).Value);
                 oDBDataSourceLines.SetValue("U_ExpDt", i - 1, ((SAPbouiCOM.EditText)oMatrix.Columns.Item("colExp").Cells.Item(i).Specific).Value);
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 SBO_Application.SetStatusBarMessage("Error setting line field values at row " + i + ": " + ex.Message, BoMessageTime.bmt_Short, true);
                 if (oCompany.InTransaction)
                     oCompany.EndTransaction(SAPbobsCOM.BoWfTransOpt.wf_RollBack);
                 return;
             }
         }

         // Update the form
         try
         {
             oForm.Update();
             if (oCompany.InTransaction)
                 oCompany.EndTransaction(SAPbobsCOM.BoWfTransOpt.wf_Commit);
             SBO_Application.SetStatusBarMessage("Record added/updated successfully.", BoMessageTime.bmt_Short, false);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             SBO_Application.SetStatusBarMessage("Error updating the record: " + ex.Message, BoMessageTime.bmt_Short, true);
             if (oCompany.InTransaction)
                 oCompany.EndTransaction(SAPbobsCOM.BoWfTransOpt.wf_RollBack);
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         SBO_Application.SetStatusBarMessage("Error handling add/update: " + ex.Message, BoMessageTime.bmt_Short, true);
         if (oCompany.InTransaction)
             oCompany.EndTransaction(SAPbobsCOM.BoWfTransOpt.wf_RollBack);
     }
 }

Need Guidance: Creating Advanced Shipping Notification Form with UDO Tables in SAP B1 SDK Using C#.NET – Source Code Not Working, Expecting Assistance to Identify Mistakes

I deleted my answer because I thought you were calling .Update() on the DIAPI object. oForm.Update() doesn't update the database, if you look in the SDK you'll see its purpose is: "Reloads the form from the application" - I think this means it refreshes from the database, not updating the database.

Yes, you are simply not doing anything in the DB. Either imitate a mouse click on the Update button on the form (e.g. via form.Items.Item("1").Click()), or work with the UDO via DI API, using the ill-named GeneralService.
